# What is the maximum size of a transaction?

Tags: transactions

I see from the source code (script.cpp) that there is an upper limit in the script size. It there any other limit to avoid a single transaction preventing other transactions of smaller sizes to get into a block?

How is this kind of attack prevented?

I've read in CTransaction::AcceptToMemoryPool the line:

```
if .... ::GetSerializeSize(*this, SER_NETWORK) < 100) 
    return error("...");
```

Does this line means that the maximum transaction size is 100 bytes?

Comment: The posted line seems to limit the minimum size, not the maximum!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a max transaction size it is much higher than 100 bytes. Not sure what that snippet is refering to but the average transaction is closer to ~300 bytes looking at the average # of transactions and block size for last 1000 blocks.

What limits transaction size is cost.  As transaction size (of all transactions awaiting next block) increases the min required fee increases non-linearly.

> 0.01 BTC fee per kilobyte of transaction, but: 
>   If the blocksize (size of all transactions currently waiting to be included in a block) is less than 27 kB, transactions are free. 
>   If the blocksize is more than 250 kB, transactions get increasingly more expensive as the blocksize approaches the limit of 500 kB. Sending a transaction when the blocksize is 400 kB will cost 5 times the normal amount; sending when it's 499 kB will cost 500x, etc.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees

So you could make a 500KB transaction but the required minimum fee would be 5BTC.  The developers have indicated they intend to change transaction fee rules in the future but given block space is a valuable commodity any new rules are likely to be constructed to encourage (via larger fees) smaller transaction sizes.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Blocks are full. Always.

Answer (score 25):

The maximum transaction size is the size of the block. [Source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3c098a8aa0780009c11b66b1a5d488a928629ebf/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L166).

```
// Size limits (this doesn't take the witness into account, as that hasn't been checked for malleability)
if (::GetSerializeSize(tx, SER_NETWORK, PROTOCOL_VERSION | SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS) * WITNESS_SCALE_FACTOR > MAX_BLOCK_WEIGHT)
    return state.DoS(100, false, REJECT_INVALID, "bad-txns-oversize");
```

Transactions larger than 100 kilobytes (including witness at a 75% discount rate) are non-standard. [Source 1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3c098a8aa0780009c11b66b1a5d488a928629ebf/src/policy/policy.h#L24). [Source 2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3c098a8aa0780009c11b66b1a5d488a928629ebf/src/net_processing.cpp#L661-L665).

```
static const unsigned int MAX_STANDARD_TX_WEIGHT = 400000;
...
if (sz >= MAX_STANDARD_TX_WEIGHT)
{
    LogPrint(BCLog::MEMPOOL, "ignoring large orphan tx (size: %u, hash: %s)\n", sz, hash.ToString());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "Transactions larger than 100 kilobytes are non-standard" has been removed. They've removed the 100 kb limit.

Comment: I disagree. It has been changed from a pure measurement of size to one of weight, but that only makes it slightly roomier - it doesn't remove it entirely.

Comment: Interesting and related: ["Non-standard transactions are frequently included by mining pools."](https://b10c.me/observations/09-non-standard-transactions/)