# How many different destinations can a single transaction have?

Tags: transactions

I am building a web-app that needs to send money to different customer's addresses. I would like to minimize transaction costs and avoid unnecesary traffic, therefore I would like to pay all of them at the same time. **How many different destinations can one single transaction have?**

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum size of a transaction?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-transaction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a maximum number of outputs but instead a maximum size of data in a block.  So if there was just one transaction with a lot of outputs, the combined size would need to be below the block maximum of 500K.

I don't know the size of each transaction but you are talking thousands or tens of thousands of outputs before hitting these per-block limits.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. So, a transaction with 200 outputs would be okay, right? :-)

Comment: That's no problem at all. I expect such a transaction to be around 7 KiB, unless you need a large amount of inputs.