# Fees for bitcoind sendmany, limits for number of end addresses

Tags: bitcoind, api

I have two questions, both about `sendmany`.

First, is there any limit on how much transactions can I send with sendmany? (Apart from bash's limit with maximal parameter length.) Is sending about 500 transactions OK?

Second, what will be the fees used when I send a lot of transactions (and thus, probably creating a big transaction)?

Comment: I would also like to know. Someone?

Comment: The upvote function is there for this very reason. Please don't use the answer field for this type of comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate your transaction size before sending the transaction. Here's some more info on that:

[How to calculate transaction size before sending](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-transaction-size-before-sending/3011#3011)

A single transaction isn't limited to how many outputs it has, rather, there are some limits to how big a block is. You can read more here:

[How many different destinations can a single transaction have?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/how-many-different-destinations-can-a-single-transaction-have/5343#5343)

EDIT:
After calculating the size, you can further calculate fees by using this method (it takes into account some code in `main.h`):

[What is the exact formula for calculating transaction fees?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/what-is-the-exact-formula-for-calculating-transaction-fees)

Comment: That is interesting. I would guess the fees are then added based on "recommended" values and the size, right?

Comment: I am accepting this answer, but if someone answers the part about fees I will be glad.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to link this thread: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/what-is-the-exact-formula-for-calculating-transaction-fees