# When I use the "send_many()" function in the blockchain.info api, have I to pay the fee only once or for each?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, python

The blockchain.info api looks like this:
[image]

The link is: https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python/blob/master/docs/wallet.md

But when I give a fee like this:

```
add={'address1':amount1,'address2':amount2}
fee=5000
pay = wallet.send_many(recipients=add,fee=fee)
```

Will it then be 10000 (two times 5000) or will it be 5000?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will pay the fee once, since it is one transaction with multiple outputs (thus only 5000).

However, also read [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22313/fees-for-bitcoind-sendmany-limits-for-number-of-end-addresses)