# What are the script size limitations according to consensus rules and are they enforced on TestNet?

Tags: script, consensus

I'm trying to figure out the limitations that scripts have regarding their size, limits that would make a script invalid (**ignoring** standardness). According to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35878/is-there-a-maximum-size-of-a-scriptsig-scriptpubkey) and also these lines of code in bitcoin core's source code [1](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3f826598a42dcc707b58224e94c394e30a42ceee/src/script/script.h#L31-L32) [2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3f826598a42dcc707b58224e94c394e30a42ceee/src/script/script.h#L22-L23) [3](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3f826598a42dcc707b58224e94c394e30a42ceee/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L299-L300) it appears that the following rules are in place:

```
Maximum script size = 10,000
Maximum data size to be pushed to the stack = 520
```

To test these rules I made a bunch of transactions on TestNet, all of which breaking some rule and were included in blocks (all sent from `n3eynMTEiGgPTuoKPApnRjE9pAuaAk3gkB`)? Example:
Tx ID: `88bac1e84c235aa0418345bf430fb43b336875974b6e87dc958de196f9222c35`
PubkeyScript `length=0xfd1527=10,005` script=`4d11275b2c...394e75`or`Push_10001_byte<5b2c...394e> OP_DROP`
As you can see the length of the script is already 10,005 > 10,000 and the first data push is 10,001 > 520. In other words I broke both rules.
Also as far as I know the "consensus" rules are exactly the same on TestNet (with one exception: difficulty adjustment), is that correct? So how is this transactions valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those consensus rules are indeed the same for testnet and mainnet.

However, they do only apply when scripts are *executed*. So you have to create an input trying to spend it to test this.

Comment: So practically this means the only limit on PubkeyScript is block size, right?

Comment: That is effectively the only consensus limit on outputs, I believe, indeed.

Comment: This is my understanding too.