# Can I send almost 1MB transaction?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, raw-transaction, full-node

Block size is still limited to 1MB. As I understood, transaction size is no longer limited. So can I be sure that my transaction with 29000 outputs and reliable fee will be included into block?
Or what is the max transaction size?

Comment: Yes, but the question and both answers are not relevant now

Comment: Related: Block 364292 is basically one massive transaction: https://blockstream.info/block/000000000000000003dd2fdbb484d6d9c349d644d8bbb3cbfa5e67f639a465fe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I send almost 1MB transaction?

To be able to send a transaction that a miner will accept, that transaction has to be a standard transaction. As defined in [`policy.h`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/eb7daf4/src/policy/policy.h#L24)

```
/** The maximum weight for transactions we're willing to relay/mine */
static const unsigned int MAX_STANDARD_TX_WEIGHT = 400000;
```

For non-Segwit transactions, the limit is `400,000 KB / 4 = 100,000 B = 100 kB`.

Therefore, if you have a Pre-Segwit transaction larger than 100 kB but smaller than the block s̶i̶z̶e weight limit, you should contact a miner, and they'll be able to add your transaction to their block manually, if it's profitable for them.

Comment: So 100kB limit still persists, I was confused by the comment to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/35882/92719 . Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any other questions, I'm happy to help.